# Responsive background image in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating responsive layout using Boot Strap 3. I am trying to use a background image as responsive. But it is not working.

Created css with background image properties and calling that class in div. Also added "img-responsive" class in same div, But the bg image is not re sizing.

Please advise.
Thank you
Monica

Comment: Please include enough relevant code so that the problem can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using
background-size: cover; or
background-size: contain;
on your background image(s) css. No need for the img-responsive class.